# GA4 - E-Commerce Purchase Event Tracking - Incorrect Values

Tags: google, google-analytics, ecommerce, conversions

I have setup the GA4 with Google Tag Manager, created tags exactly as described in the [Dev Guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtm)

I have several issues:

- The purchase event count is not the same as the real orders count (more than 10% conversions are missing)
- When I navigate to the page: `Reports` > `Monetization` > `Ecommerce purchases` There is a grid report displaying some data about the items (view count - added to cart - items purchased). I see stats are displayed even though it is not accurate, however, the numbers are somehow not exaggerated, except for one column **Items Viewed**. I see for some products they have the view count: `9,999,999`! Which is for sure impossible to happen.
  Knowing that when opening the "Debug View" and navigate through the products, the `view_item` event gets triggered only once every time I open the product page.

[image]

Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, GA4 will always be missing some data due to its dependence on running code and requesting resources via the user's browser. Many users block tracking or advertising code. 10% loss is about right. If you have a consent banner, expect a lot more loss.

For the second question, it's hard to guess. You could create a report focusing on the view_item event to see when it gets triggered and what it contains. It also looks like there is an item_id disconnect between the view_item and the other events, causing only one item to show data. Maybe this is happening because of bad item_ids in your view_item?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you "Tony McCreath" for giving this explanation, I believe this is correct regarding the first point. However, for the second point I have finally figured out what is this and why I see these big numbers, this is because the **quantity** field in the code snippet. I will explain:

[image]

The quantity field for this item is affecting the items viewed column in the GA4 dashboard

[image]

So when you set the quantity to `1` then when ever a user visits this product it will increase the `items viewed` count with the 1.
If you have set (like in my case) the quantity field to the real quantity. Then when ever a user visits this item, **the viewed items will be increased with the real quantity value**.

So if an item has a quantity of `200`, when it gets visited for the first time, the viewed items for this product will be `200`, if it is visited 6 times, then the count will be `1200`.

I have set the quantity to be 1 for all products. Not sure if this will affect anything but I went with this solution.